# C2011: 'Card': 'class' type redefinition (despite using include guards and not redefining class in .cpp file)

Tags: c++

Note: I've been reading some articles on this error, but the main problem seems to fall under either one of these:

1.They didn't use include guards (specifically #ifndef)

2.They redefined the class in the .h file, *as well as* in the .cpp file

But I didn't have either of those issues, so I don't think this is a duplicate.

---

In my Card.h file, I used include guards:

```
#ifndef CARD_HEADER
#define CARD_HEADER
#endif

class Card
{
    //Code here
};
```

And in my .cpp file, there wasn't any class redefinition:

```
#include "Card.h"

//Code here
```

So now, I have no clue as to what's going on. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You must put the #endif at the end of the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your guard is correct.  Try this:

```
#ifndef CARD_HEADER
#define CARD_HEADER

class Card
{
    //Code here
}
#endif
```

Remember, the whole point is to *EXCLUDE* your code if the header has already been used at least once (if `#ifdef CARD_HEADER` is true).

Look here for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Anyways, thanks a lot! I think I misunderstood how these include guards work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following for preventing multiple inclusions of the header files.

```
#pragma once
class Card
{
    //Code here
};
```